# Unable to acces site after unwanted cancelling of plugin-installation

Tags: php, plugins, joomla

After trying to install a plugin on my website I'm unable to access the site (front- and backend).

> [php7:error] [pid 10111]PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin' not found in
>   /home/public/sites/www.modderaandebanden.nl/plugins/system/sessiongc/sessiongc.php
>   on line 22 [Sat Jul 21 17:34:46.681638 2018] [:error] [pid 11113]  PHP
>   Fatal error:  Class 'Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin' not found in
>   /home/public/sites/www.modderaandebanden.nl/plugins/system/sessiongc/sessiongc.php
>   on line 23

This seems to be the problem but I'm not sure what I should do. Already tried the solution in "user3063937" problem but this doesn't work for me (change sessiongc folder to sessiongc.bak).

Any suggestions what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to phpmyadmin, login and open your database for your site.  Navigate to the #__extensions table, search for the plugin and disable there.

Comment: Thanks. I looked for the plugin but I couldn't find it. Meanwhile my website displays error message when opening: Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL

Comment: Have you contacted your host?  If it is a giving a mySQL connection problem and have you haven't changed your credentials lately,  etc, then it might be an issue with mySQL itself.  Many times having your host restart the service will solve that.

Comment: Ah thanks. Yes, tried contacting my host but they're little slow in response at the moment. Have let them know the current status, hopefully they can fix it. I'll keep you updated. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Back at the PHP error.... Hmmm, doesn't seem to solve itself (LOL). Does reinstalling Joomla and putting up a backup with Akeeba should solve things or is that just stupid thinking?

Bram

Comment: It might.  Worth a try.